# java method that returns patterned string from range

Tags: java, string

I'm brand new to Java. I've been assigned a test and I'm stuck on how to complete it. So the case is like so -

> Create a method that returns a patterned string from range A000 to ZZZZ. Parameter for the method is string itself, so if we pass A000 it should return A001, if we pass A001 it should return A002 and so on... A009... A999... AA00... AA99... AB00... AB01... AB99... AC00... to AZZZ.

I've been able to increment the numbers, but am unable to change them to letters when they reach 99. Let's say I input AZ99; it should return AZA0, but I don't know how I should write that logic.

I thought of using arrays, but then I'd have to save each iteration of the pattern in the array, and that seems unfeasible. Then I thought I'd use if...else and write the instances where the numbers should increment into letters, but that's unnecessarily long too. I know this can be done by proper logic, but it fails me. I've scrounged multiple threads on stackoverflow, but I can't find one quite like this one.

This is what I've got so far -

```
public class StringSeries {

  public static String returnString (String inputString) {
    String newString = inputString.substring(0,2);
    String completeNewString = newString + 
        (Integer.parseInt(inputString.substring(1,inputString.length()))+1);
    System.out.println(completeNewString);
    return completeNewString;
  }

  public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner();
    String inputString = sc.nextLine();
    returnString(inputString);
    sc.close();
  }
}
```

I need suggestions on how to do this. Also, please elaborate on how a certain logic would work.

Thanks!

P.S. I've looked a lot for this type of question on forums, and haven't been able to find any. I also realize that this question may be repetitive for non-newbies. I request that you don't be rude and point out similar threads if you know where they are. Thanks.

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base36 and then just convert from Base36 to number, then increment, and convert back to Base36.

Comment: To start with - you're assuming the first two characters will never change. What happens when you run your code with "AZZZ"?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the Base36 encoding? If not you will have to implement it yourself. Try to search for Base36 implementation.

Answer (score 5):

This is much easier than it seems. All you need to do is convert the string to a number in base 36 ([`Integer.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(java.lang.String,int)), [`Integer.parseUnsignedInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseUnsignedInt(java.lang.String,int))), add one to it, and convert it to an upper case base-36 string ([`Integer.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString(int,int)) plus converting that to upper case).

Comment: This is corerect idea but it is base 16 not 36. and I would suggest to use methods Integer.parseUnsignedInt(s, 16) and Integer.toHexString(int i)

Comment: @MichaelGantman - `0` to `Z` is base 36. (Good point about `parseUnsignedInt`!)

Comment: My mistake about 16 - 36. You are correct, it is base 36